# SocketStream sending Hex values

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to translate a code from .c to Delphi. And in this .c application, all socket communication is made via hexadecimal values. The first communication is:

> C Code: unsigned char bufSend1[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

Which in Delphi I did:

> SockStream.WriteBuffer(#0#0#0#0, 4);

But now, in C I have things like:

> unsigned char bufSend2[] = { 0x6f, 0x06, 0xff };

How can I send this values via socketstream? And the #0#0#0#0 what the right way to do that?

Comment: A Delphi version would help here. Ken's answer only works for D2007 or earlier. For D2009 and later it fails, as you have discovered. Now, I can tell that you are using D2009+ but it would be good for the question to be tagged with your Delphi version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply encode it as a Delphi character, using hex notation.

In Delphi, hex is indicated by a `$` prefix, and `#` indicates `Char`. So the equivalent of your `bufSend2` values would be:

```
SocketStream.WriteBuffer(#$6f#$06#$ff, 3);
```

`#` indicates the next value is a `Char`, and `$6f` indicates the hex value (equivalent to `0x6f` in C). You simply put them one after the other, the same as you did with your `#0#0#0#0` values.

A better solution would be to properly cast each to the appropriate `AnsiChar` value, which works fine if you're sending a small number of characters:

```
SocketStream.WriteBuffer(AnsiChar(#$6f) + AnsiChar(#$06) + AnsiChar(#$ff), 3);
```

The best solution, however, would be to use an `array of Byte`:

```
// Static array
var
  Buff: array[0..100] of Byte;


  Buff[0] := $6f;
  Buff[1] := $06;
  Buff[2] := $ff;
  SocketStream.WriteBuffer(Buff[0], 3);

// Dynamic array
var
  Buff: array of Byte;

  SetLength(Buff, 3);
  Buff[0] := $6f;
  Buff[1] := $06;
  Buff[2] := $ff;
  SocketStream.WriteBuffer(Buff[0], Length(Buff));
```

To add text to either array, simply use `Ord(AnsiChar(Letter))`, such as

```
var
  s: AnsiString;
  i: Integer;
  Len: Integer;

s := 'Test';
Len := Length(s);
SetLength(Buff, Len);

for i := 1 to Len do    
  Buff[i - 1] := Ord(AnsiChar(s[i]));

SocketStream.WriteBuffer(Buff[0], Len);
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your answer, but I didn't got any valid answer from server. So I looked in wireshark what really was sent, and I got: 
**Value: 670006 [Length: 3]**, I don't think that is the correct value for the respectives hex 0x6f, 0x06, 0xFF... What's wrong?

Comment: @user1526124, typo? `#$67` should be `#$6f` to match yours.

Comment: Yes, I note that... For some unknown reason I keep getting unknown responses from server. Anyway I believe the hex doubt was cleared. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Yep. I'll fix it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user1526124: What Delphi version are you using? It looks like perhaps you're using D2009 or higher, which makes `Char` more than a single byte in size; your C code uses `unsigned char`, which is probably 1 byte. If that's the case, you need to cast each of the char values to `AnsiChar`. I'm not sure what `SockStream` is, so I don't know what parameters are expected for `WriteBuffer`.

Comment: `PAnsiChar(#$6f#$06#$ff)^` does the job in Unicode Delphi but that seems rather vile to me. I'm never quite sure what it really means. Perhaps I just need to man up and learn what it means! Anyway, for Unicode Delphi I think such string literals are not the best option here.

Comment: @David: If the receiving end is expecting to be sent those characters specifically, there's no problem in just casting them to `AnsiChar` values; I don't think there's anything "vile" (although I wouldn't do it with `PAnsiChar()^`; I'd cast each single character instead with `AnsiChar`).

Comment: @KenWhite That gets tiresome with more characters. That looks like: `SockStream.WriteBuffer(AnsiChar(#$6f)+AnsiChar(#$06)+AnsiChar(#$ff), 3);` which is not really to my taste either. Frankly I'm not wild about any of the options here. If Delphi let me define a constant in the middle of the function, that would be nice. Or a structured literal like C# or modern C/C++.

Comment: @David: Agreed, on all counts. :)

Comment: Using character strings to send binary data - especially in D2009+ and especially for values > $7F - is the **WRONG** answer. You should be using byte arrays instead (which is what the C code is doing), eg: `bufSend1: array[0..3] of Byte = ($00, $00, $00, $00); SockStream.WriteBuffer(bufSend1[0], 4);` and `bufSend2: array[0..2] of Byte = ($6f, $06, $ff); SockStream.WriteBuffer(bufSend2[0], 3);`

Comment: @Remy: I respect your superior knowledge in this topic. However, there's no indication (prior to the wireshark comment posted to my answer) that this was D2009+. I personally would not use character strings to send binary data, but my opinion is not what the question here asked. Legacy code (pre-2009) often used this method of transmitting data, and it appeared this was such code based on the initial (and current) question itself. (I've always understood that "string" is not "binary data", and have never confused the two in code I've written.)

Comment: @Remy bufSend1 is better than bufSend1[0] since you don't have to hard code the lower array bound

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: if `bufSend1` is a static array, then yes. But if it were changed to a dynamic array later on then the dereference is required in order to pass the correct address. So I err on the side of caution and use a single syntax that works for both.

Comment: I'm pleased that you have addressed the criticisms and improved the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are calling [`TWinSocketStream.Write`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TWinSocketStream.Write). That is declared as so:

```
function Write(const Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
```

The untyped `const` parameter can receive anything. You want to pass a byte array. There are a few ways of doing so. For example:

```
const
  bufSend2: array [0..2] of Byte = ($6f, $06, $ff);
....
SockStream.WriteBuffer(bufSend2, SizeOf(bufSend2));
```

Or

```
SockStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(TBytes.Create($6f, $06, $ff))^, 3);
```

I think personally I prefer the former. It's a little more verbose. But you don't have to hard-code the byte count, and you avoid heap allocation.